# Trouble with iterative addition in C

Tags: c, standard-deviation

I have several huge matrices of data to process, 1000 x 1000 x 400,000. I usually use Matlab, and my Matlab script takes 9 hours to process one data set. So I'm trying to put it into C.

The problem is, when I calculate the standard deviation of my data, C and Matlab don't match. They are not even close.

```
for(std=0;std<Ndat;std++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<MAXPAIR;j++)
      {
        dist=distance(polymer[GoPair[j].a1],polymer[GoPair[j].a2]);

        if(dist<=(GoPair[j].dist+PREFACTOR))
          {
            Stan[j] += ((1-Prob[j])*(1-Prob[j]));;
          }
        else if(dist>(GoPair[j].dist+PREFACTOR))
          {
            Stan[j] += ((0-Prob[j])*(0-Prob[j]));
          }
      }
  }

for(j=0;j<MAXPAIR;j++)
  {
    stnDev[j] = sqrt(Stan[j]/Ndat);
  }
```

The idea is that `Stan[j]` should have `(1-Prob[j])^2` or `(0-Prob[j])^2` added to what ever is already in that array position each time the loop runs, but it's not returning the same values that Matlab does for virtually the same script.

Do any of you see basic errors or have any idea why this isn't working for me?

Comment: What are the data-types of all variables involved? What values are you expecting, and what values do you actually get?

Comment: Add variable declarations. What is `Stan`?

Comment: Variables are all double.

Comment: In order for us to be able to help answer a question, you have to provide us with a complete example - see ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You might want to run your scripts on a much smaller data set, and see whether you can reproduce the problem. At the very least, do only one iteration of the loop `for(j=0;j<MAXPAIR;j++)` to reduce debugging time by a factor of 1000. See also [mcve].

Comment: Did you correctly initialize your arrays?

Comment: For stnDev[1] I'm expecting 0.1530, but I'm getting 0.0239. Similar results for all other array positions.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. The variables, i, j, std, etc. are int type. the data variables I am working with are all double type.

Comment: Where do you zero `Stan[]` before summing to it?

Comment: `(0-x)*(0-x)` is the same as `x*x`, so I have to wonder whether you translated that part correctly.

Comment: What is your `distance` function?

Comment: There is a redundant `else if()` too when you already made that test.

Comment: Seems to be a pretty strange standard deviation - it usually works on the square of the difference from the arithmetical mean of the values, not imposing conditions.

Comment: Stan[] is zeroed at the beginning of the fuction. 'double Stan[MAXPAIR]={0.0};'. This is a small snippet of a much bigger function to calculate correlation. This is the only part giving me trouble.

Comment: That will only work if the float-encoded value of `0.0` is the `0` with which the remainder of initialised memory is filled.

Comment: @WeatherVane: That initialization looks fine to me. C11 draft standard 1570: *6.7.9 Initialization 10 [...]
— if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
— if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;[...]*

Comment: @WeatherVane The redundant else if is due to another distance function it will call if the distance is greater. I left it out for brevity. Also, I'm looking at contacts made between particles, so either it's in contact or not, hence the binary standard deviation.

Comment: @yellowantphil: The distance function is: 'double distance(struct config poly1, struct config poly2)
{

  double dist;

  dist = ( (poly1.x-poly2.x)*(poly1.x-poly2.x)+(poly1.y-poly2.y)*(poly1.y-poly2.y) + (poly1.z-poly2.z)*(poly1.z-poly2.z) );

  return sqrt(dist);'

Comment: That distance function is used many times through out the program, and doesn't give me any trouble.

Comment: @Caleb You can [edit] your post to include valuable info. Assume the comments will be purged soon by moderators; your post should contain all necessary info.

Comment: Also, consider adding your input data, expected output and actual output to the question. However, replace your actual data by some smaller example.

Comment: I figured it out. I was using fscanf() to read through a data file, but another function had used that data file earlier in the program. I had to use rewind() to start at the beginning of the file again. Thanks for all of the comments.